# Show div on image click in Galleria.io

Tags: jquery, galleria

I've been at this for three days and really figured its time to ask for help. I am running galleria fullscreen and I want to be able to show a hidden div on-click. I've wrapped the image in a div and tried calling it as shown bellow but Nothing I've tried seem to work. What am  I missing please

```
<div class="galleria">

 <div id ='showdiv'>
 <img src=\"$fullpath\",data-description=\"$datadescr\">
 </div>

 </div>
```

---

```
<script>
$(function() {
Galleria.loadTheme('http://example.net/galleria.fullscreen.min.js');
Galleria.run('.galleria', {
transition: 'fade',
imageCrop: false
});
});
</script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#showdiv').click(function(){
 alert("try");
//show div function
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

created a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kf5521kx/2/

click on the image to invoke Galleria.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#showdiv').click(function(){
  Galleria.loadTheme('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/galleria/1.5.6/themes/fullscreen/galleria.fullscreen.js');
      Galleria.run('.galleria', {
      transition: 'fade',
      imageCrop: false
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your time. I want to be able to click on any slide in the gallery and have the hidden div shown